# updating table removes the data from columns which are not bound in jsp page

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc

i have a table which have many columns. When i update some of the columns using @ModelAttribute, the data from the columns which are not specified in jsp page is removed.

example

```
@RequestMapping(value= "/studenteducation", method= RequestMethod.GET)
public String setupUpdateEducationForm(Model model, @ModelAttribute("education") Student student){

    student = studentService.getStudent(getStudentName());
    model.addAttribute("education", student);  //adding saved student data into model
    return "studenteducation";
}

@RequestMapping(value= "/studenteducation", method= RequestMethod.POST)
public String studentEducationForm(Model model, @ModelAttribute("education") Student student, BindingResult result){

    if(result.hasErrors()){
        return "studenteducation";          
    }

    student.setStudentId(getStudentName()); // inserting primary key
    studentService.updateStudent(student);  // updating student table

    return "redirect:/";        
}
```

the problem is that i am not binding all the columns in this update and thus only bound columns data is left and other columns data is removed from the database. I have like 15 columns and i am binding 5 columns in this jsp page.

My full Controller Code :

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/user")
@SessionAttributes("education")
public class StudentController {

@Autowired
StudentService studentService;
Student student = new Student();

// Setup new Student form------------------------------------------------------------------ 

@RequestMapping(value= "/newuser", method= RequestMethod.GET)
public String setupAddStudentForm(Model model, @ModelAttribute("student") Student student){

    return "registerstudent";
}

// Add new Student------------------------------------------------------------------    

@RequestMapping(value= "/newuser", method= RequestMethod.POST)
public String sddStudent(Model model, @ModelAttribute("student") Student student, BindingResult result, SessionStatus sessionStatus){

    if(result.hasErrors()){
        return "registerstudent";
    }
    studentService.addStudent(student); 
    sessionStatus.setComplete();
    return "redirect:/";
}

// Setup Edit Profile Form------------------------------------------------------------------    

@RequestMapping(value= "/updateprofile", method= RequestMethod.GET)
public String setupStudentProfileForm(Model model, @ModelAttribute("profile") Student student ){

    Student stu = studentService.getStudent(getStudentName());
    model.addAttribute("name", student.getStudentId());
    model.addAttribute("studentprofile", stu);
    return "studentprofile";        
}

// Update student profile------------------------------------------------------------------ 

@RequestMapping(value= "/updateprofile", method= RequestMethod.POST)
public String studentProfileForm(Model model, @ModelAttribute("profile") Student student, BindingResult result, SessionStatus sessionStatus ){

    if(result.hasErrors()){
        return "studentprofile";            
    }

    student.setStudentId(getStudentName());
    studentService.updateStudent(student);      
    sessionStatus.setComplete();
    return "redirect:/";        
}

// Setup Update Education Form------------------------------------------------------------------    

@RequestMapping(value= "/studenteducation", method= RequestMethod.GET)
public String setupUpdateEducationForm(Model model, @ModelAttribute("education") Student student){

    student = studentService.getStudent(getStudentName());
    model.addAttribute("education", student);
    return "studenteducation";
}

// Update Student Education------------------------------------------------------------------   

@RequestMapping(value= "/studenteducation", method= RequestMethod.POST)
public String studentEducationForm(Model model, @ModelAttribute("education") Student student, BindingResult result, SessionStatus sessionStatus){

    if(result.hasErrors()){
        return "studenteducation";          
    }

    student.setStudentId(getStudentName());
    studentService.updateStudent(student);
    sessionStatus.setComplete();
    return "redirect:/";        
}
```

My Student model id large and i am updating it by 2 controllers. Student profile in different jsp page and education in different jsp page with different controllers. When i update one portion the other portion deletes.

Comment: Are there any triggers on the table?

Comment: no, its just simple table with hibernate annotation @Entity.

Comment: is there any other way a better way to update table in hibernate . I am using  getSessionFactory.update(student)

Answer (score 1):

This is what [@SessionAttributes](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/SessionAttributes.html) is for

Add `@SessionAttributes("education")` on top of your Controller class declaration

Get rid of the `@ModelAttribute("education") Student student` parameter in your first method. Add a student to the model in that method instead.

Add a `SessionStatus` parameter to your POST handler method and call `sessionStatus.setComplete()` when you're done.

You should be using the [Post-Redirect-Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern.

You should also be using @InitBinder to set disallowed fields if users are not supposed to edit some entity fields in this form:

```
@InitBinder
public void setAllowedFields(WebDataBinder dataBinder) {
  dataBinder.setDisallowedFields("foo");
}
```

Comment: It is giving exception org.springframework.web.HttpSessionRequiredException: Expected session attribute 'education'. I have updated the question with new code plz check

Comment: You might need to load default sessionattributes with a @modelattribute METHOD

Comment: how sir ? I could not find any examples on this.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29039116/how-to-partially-update-record-with-spring-mvc-and-use-post-redirect-get-patte/29039117#29039117

Answer (score 1):

It is the way Spring MVC and Hibernate work together. When you write in your controller method un `@ModelAttribute("education") Student student`, Spring MVC creates a new object and populates it with form data. All other fields keep their initialization values (generally null).
You may find it stupid, but I have never found a nice and clean way to deal with that in Spring MVC. Common workarounds :

- Use `SessionAttributes` as suggested by Neil McGuigan. The problem is that the attribute can stay in session when you no longer need it, and it cannot obviously be used for sessionless API usage.
- pass the id in URL and use a `Converter` to convert it into the correct `Student` object. But you have to call the persistance layer outside the service layer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I just took easy way out. I split my student table into 2 different tables and now updating full columns in jsp page. So it solved my problem of getting null values in already filled unused columns.