# Validate part of object Spring

Tags: validation, spring-mvc

I want to validate different properties of object based on the occasion. For an example lets say I have a User object

```
public class User{
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String age;
}
```

When adding a user I want to validate all fields. But when user reset a password there would be username and password. If Spring validator tries to validate age as well it'll be a failure.

Is there a way that I can tell Spring validator to only validate a certain subset of object properties.

Comment: You can use JSR-303 validation annotations combined with Spring's [`Validated`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/annotation/Validated.html) annotation which allows you to specify validation groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To partially update an entity, you should use @SessionAttributes to store the model in session between requests. You could use hidden form fields, but session is more secure.
2. To secure fields use webDataBinder.setAllowedFields("field1","field2",...) or create a class specific to the form then copy values to your entity.
3. Use Validation Groups + @Validated. Though in this case it might just be easier to use separate Form Backing Objects.

See my answer here: [Spring MVC: Validation, Post-Redirect-Get, Partial Updates, Optimistic Concurrency, Field Security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29039116/spring-mvc-validation-post-redirect-get-partial-updates-optimistic-concurren)