# Spring boot PATCH

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-rest

As I read fron documentation (https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-rest/)

> PUT replaces an entire record. Fields not supplied will be replaced
>   with null. PATCH can be used to update a subset of items.

So, I try to use PATCH for my User entity with 2 fields (name and surname)

```
@RequestMapping(path="/user/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PATCH)
public User updateUser ( User user) {       
    return userRepository.save(user);
}
```

When I send to:

> localhost:8080/user/34

body with  `name: "user" and surname: "testSurname"` it works well.
but when I send only `name (without surname)`, **surname** also updates to **null**.

How can I prevent spring boot from update fields with null values?

Comment: `userRepository.save(department)` what is `department` ? did you mean `userRepository.save(user)` ?

Comment: The guide you have linked to is about Spring Data REST which provides RESTful endpoints for you. In your question you have written your own endpoint where it's up to you to decide how `PATCH` should behave

Comment: I've put together a [post](https://cassiomolin.com/using-http-patch-in-spring/) that describes an approach for using `PATCH` in Spring. And a working example is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/cassiomolin/http-patch-spring).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not using Spring Data Rest here. You're using spring data jpa repository `userRepository.save(department);`

and Spring MVC by creating your custom http endpoint.

```
@RequestMapping(path="/user/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PATCH)
public User updateUser ( User user) {...
```

To see the patch behavior that you described you have to use the endpoint that is exposed by spring data rest, not a custom one that you've made. 
When you create a custom endpoint it will do exactly what you code it to do, spring will not mess with your code and alter the behavior.

Comment: I cant find any useful info about that. Can you give some example please ?

Comment: @Sever You can find a lot of info on the official pages of the projects - http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-rest/ and http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-jpa/ You may want to check the concepts of the projects (what they're suppose to do). The guides that you've already found are also a good resource.

Comment: Hi, Is it possible to have a custom http endpoint but still have spring update the entity with the new values from the HTTP request? So i can manually process the now updated entity in the customer method?

Comment: @user2049132 Sorry I didn't understand the question

Comment: @EvgeniDimitrov I want to use a custom http endpoint but have spring merge the updated values from the request to the entity when i use it in the method. 
Inside this method
`@RequestMapping(path="/user/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PATCH)
public User updateUser ( User user) {`

Comment: @EvgeniDimitrov I want to do something similar to the answer [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31768289/spring-data-jpa-how-to-update-a-model-elegantly) but for REST API without using modelattribute

Comment: @user2049132 The equivalent of `@ModelAttribute` in rest services is `@RequestBody`. Try that