# Avoid Spring MVC form resubmission when refreshing the page

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am using spring MVC to save the data into database. Problem is it's resubmitting the JSP page when I am refreshing the page.
                     Below is my code snippet

```
<c:url var="addNumbers" value="/addNumbers" ></c:url>
<form:form action="${addNumbers}" commandName="AddNumber" id="form1">

</<form:form>
```

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addNumbers",  method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addCategory(@ModelAttribute("addnum") AddNumber num){
    this.numSrevice.AddNumbers(num);
    return "number";
}
```

Answer (score 10):

You have to implement [Post/Redirect/Get](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).

Once the POST method is completed instead of returning a view name send a redirect request using `"redirect:<pageurl>"`.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addNumbers",  method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addCategory(@ModelAttribute("addnum") AddNumber num){
    this.numSrevice.AddNumbers(num);
    return "redirect:/number";
}
```

And and have a method with `method = RequestMethod.GET` there return the view name.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/number",  method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String category(){
    return "number";
}
```

So the post method will give a redirect response to the browser then the browser will fetch the redirect url using get method since resubmission is avoided

**Note**: I'm assuming that you don't have any `@RequestMapping` at controller level. If so append that mapping before `/numbers` in `redirect:/numbers`

Answer (score 2):

You can return a `RedirectView` from the handler method, initialized with the URL:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addNumbers",  method = RequestMethod.POST)
public View addCategory(@ModelAttribute("addnum") AddNumber num,
                        HttpServletRequest request){
    this.numSrevice.AddNumbers(num);
    String contextPath = request.getContextPath();
    return new RedirectView(contextPath + "/number");
}
```

Comment: Thnaks @Evil Toad! I want to redirect on the same view from where I am calling /addNumber after POST

Comment: just change the URL then (The constructor's parameter of `RedirectView`)

Answer (score 2):

My [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29039116/spring-mvc-validation-post-redirect-get-partial-updates-optimistic-concurren) shows how to do this, including validation error messages.

Another option is to use Spring Web Flow, which can do this automatically for you.