# how to redirect properly in springmvc

Tags: java, validation, spring-mvc, redirect

I'm having a problem like this.

1. I'm in page-1 with URL-1
2. When I click submit in page-1, validation is going on the controller via URL-2 before showing page-2. But there are errors and the validation failed.
3. So I should still see page-1. But the URL is URL-2 whose naming doesn't match with page-1.

How can I solve this? I find it hard to redirect the errors back to page-1.

Comment: Why do you collect output of page-1 on URL-2 and not on URL-1? You could collect it on URL-1 and, if everything is ok, redirect to URL-2 after the form post is processed.

Comment: this one explains how to do post-redirect-get validation with spring: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29039116/spring-mvc-validation-post-redirect-get-partial-updates-optimistic-concurren